# how to create Menu in android like this picture

Tags: android, eclipse, menu

I Need to build a menu in android - eclipse 
Like the picture below but i don't even know the name for this menu

[image]

Comment: This is tabs in bottom. You can go for the tabbar in android

Comment: Just a soft reminder about [pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html). It's a guideline, but you're free to ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu which you want to develop is called TabBar in android. You can create TabBar in bottom Using FragmentTabHost. Its implementation is provided on [Android:Bottom Tab Bar Control](http://www.kpbird.com/2011/05/androidbottom-tabbar-control.html)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial: http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html

It shows how to make iOS style tabs. Though you might need customization to adjust the theme.

Answer (score 0):

this bottomTabBar Using FragmentTabHost , this is not any Menu bar with button